Bluetooth LE Connection Cancellations with aioble on Raspberry Pi Pico W
Setting & Problem
I'm developing a Bluetooth Low Energy application using MicroPython (v1.22.2) with the aioble library for a peripheral device (Raspberry Pi Pico W) and Python's bluepy library for a central device running on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+. I'm facing an issue where the BLE connection gets repeatedly cancelled after a few seconds (10-20s). The peripheral sends notifications about a sensor's state (open/close), and the central device receives these notifications.
Here's a simplified version of what happens:

The central device connects to the peripheral.
The peripheral sends a few notifications.
Suddenly, the connection gets cancelled.

Code snippet on the peripheral side:
# Bluetooth GATT setup
_DOOR_SERVICE_UUID = bluetooth.UUID('12345678-1234-5678-1234-56789abcdef0')
_DOOR_STATE_UUID = bluetooth.UUID('12345678-1234-5678-1234-56789abcdef1')
_ADV_APPEARANCE_GENERIC_DOOR_SENSOR = const(768)
_ADV_INTERVAL_MS = 250_000

door_service = aioble.Service(_DOOR_SERVICE_UUID)
door_state_characteristic = aioble.Characteristic(door_service, _DOOR_STATE_UUID, read=True, notify=True)
aioble.register_services(door_service)
...
...
# Bluetooth advertising task
async def peripheral_task():
    global current_connection
    while True:
        if not current_connection:
            print("No Connection, attempting to advertise")
            try:
                async with await aioble.advertise(
                    _ADV_INTERVAL_MS,
                    name="DoorSensor",
                    services=[_DOOR_SERVICE_UUID],
                    appearance=_ADV_APPEARANCE_GENERIC_DOOR_SENSOR,
                ) as connection:
                    current_connection = connection
                    print("Connection from", connection.device)
                    await connection.disconnected()
            except asyncio.CancelledError as e:
                print(f"Cancelled: {str(e)}")
                current_connection = None
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Unhandled exception: {str(e)}")
            finally:
                current_connection = None
        else:
            if not current_connection.is_connected():
                print("lost connection")
            print("connected")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
...
# loop which checks door state and notifies central
...
    if current_connection:
        door_state_characteristic.notify(current_connection, _encode_door_state(1))
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

Code on central side:
from bluepy.btle import Peripheral, DefaultDelegate

class MyDelegate(DefaultDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        DefaultDelegate.__init__(self)

    def handleNotification(self, cHandle, data):
        print("Notification from Handle: {}".format(cHandle))
        state = int.from_bytes(data, byteorder='little')
        print("Door State Changed:", "Open" if state else "Closed")

def connect_to_sensor():
    peri = Peripheral("D8:3A:DD:9E:82:B1", "public")
    peri.setDelegate(MyDelegate())

    print("Connected to device")

    # Get service and characteristic
    svc = peri.getServiceByUUID("12345678-1234-5678-1234-56789abcdef0")
    ch = svc.getCharacteristics("12345678-1234-5678-1234-56789abcdef1")[0]

    print("Service and characteristic found")

    # Correct CCCD UUID for enabling notifications
    cccd_uuid = "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
    cccd = ch.getDescriptors(forUUID=cccd_uuid)[0]
    cccd.write(b"\x01\x00", True)  # Enable notifications

    print("Subscribed to notifications")

    return peri

p = None

while True:
    if p:
        try:
            if p.waitForNotifications(1.0):
                continue
            print("Waiting for notifications...")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"got some weird error\n{e}")
            p = None
    elif not p:
        p = connect_to_sensor()
        
p.disconnect()

What I tried so far:

I implemented a reconnection strategy in the peripheral device’s script that immediately restarts advertising after a cancellation occurs.
I added exception handling in both the peripheral and central scripts to catch and log any errors that occur during the connection or notification handling processes.

Expectations:

I expected that by restarting the advertising immediately after a disconnection, the system would maintain a near-continuous availability for reconnection by the central device.
I hoped that the detailed error logging would reveal specific reasons for the cancellations or disconnections, helping me to pinpoint and address the underlying issue.

On going problem:

While the reconnection strategy does allow the system to quickly recover from disconnections, it results in a cycle of repeated cancellations and reconnections that seem to occur without any clear pattern or error message, making it difficult to diagnose the root cause.
The error logs have not shown any specific exceptions or errors that could explain why the cancellations are occurring. The only output is typically "Cancelled" with no further details.

Output on peripheral
No Connection, attempting to advertise
Connection from Device(ADDR_PUBLIC, e4:aa:ea:fb:e0:32, CONNECTED)
It's open # notification
It's open # notification
Cancelled: 
No Connection, attempting to advertise
Connection from Device(ADDR_PUBLIC, e4:aa:ea:fb:e0:32, CONNECTED)
It's open # notification
Cancelled: 
No Connection, attempting to advertise
Connection from Device(ADDR_PUBLIC, e4:aa:ea:fb:e0:32, CONNECTED)
It's open # notification
It's open # notification

Test with bluetoothctl
Testing the connection from my machine (Ubuntu 22.04) with bluetoothctl seem to indicate that the peripheral drops the connection and not the central.

It would be helpful if you could identify if it is the peripheral or the central that is causing the issue. One thing to try is using a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool (e.g. nRF Connect) to test the peripheral. If that is stable then we can focus on the central.

It seems that the peripheral is causing the issue. I connected from my machine (Ubuntu 22.04) with the peripheral via bluetoothctl and just waited, after some time the connection was dropped. This was the output at the end:
[CHG] Device D8:3A:DD:9E:82:B1 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device D8:3A:DD:9E:82:B1 Connected: no

The unintentional disconnect may be caused by the default timeout_ms of
await connection.disconnected()
in your peripheral code.
I would use:
await connection.disconnected(timeout_ms=None)
